# Using superscript in C# resource file

Tags: c#, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have some superscript text that I need to define in a C# UI project resource file that will eventually be put in a XAML datatable.
For instance the 2 in this example needs to be superscript:  **(kg/m2)**

Is there any way to define this right in the Value field of the Resource string...perhaps via a Unicode or HTML tag that a standard Xaml control bound to this value could parse?
I'm not opposed to using a XAML converter, but short of putting some sort of hacky string in the resource (e.g.**(kg/mSQUARED)**) and using the XAML to look for it, I can't think of an elegant way to that either.

Thanks!

Comment: how about simply using ^2 in the text and then make sure to escape ^ (e.g. ^^) where ever that should actually be part of the text?

Comment: If "squared" is the only one you need, there's a Unicode code point for that: ² (U+00B2, or `"\u00B2"` in code)

Comment: @JoeWhite Neither one of those sequences works when bound to a TextBox from a resource file.

Comment: I gave you three sequences, not two. I just repeated the first one (which is probably the one you missed, and also the one most immediately useful to you) in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment above, it sounds like "squared" is the only one you need. So, to amplify my comment:

There's already a Unicode code point for "squared" aka "SUPERSCRIPT TWO". It's called U+00B2, if you want to Google more information about it.

Here it is:

> ²

Highlight that character in your Web browser, copy it to the clipboard, and paste it into your resource file.

Comment: That works. Moral of the story is to copy that superscript character from a web browser (or some non-Microsoft text editor).  I had already tried copying from Word, which stripped the formatting when I pasted into the Resource file. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: If you had added a `2` to Word and then formatted it as superscript, then it would have copied out as a `2` (U+0032) because that's what it is. Same thing if you put `<sup>2</sup>` into a Web page and tried to copy it: you'd just get `2`. That's why I put a U+00B2 into my answer, not a superscripted U+0032.

Answer (score 0):

Use US International keyboard layout, Press Alt-Gr + 2, that will show

Alt-Gr + 3 = ³